# How to completely remove spam bots from Telegram groups?

Tags: telegram

I'm managing a small Telegram groups. Unfortunately a couple of days ago a user added a bot to the group. I immediately removed/banned that user and the bot. However all other member still see the bot on their Telegram messenger:

[image]

which when selected expands to:

[image]

I have looked everywhere but for the love of god I can't find any way to remove it entirely from the group. I would appreciate if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the bot that has been added sent a ReplyKeyboard as its ReplyMarkup. This ReplyMarkup are the button(s) you see at the bottom of the chat. To remove this you might want to add a bot that can send AND remove the Keyboard.

I know that [@combot](https://t.me/combot) can do this with it's command `!nokeyboard`. This will send a keyboard to everyone in the chat and instantly remove it.

Hopefully this will help.